# Getting RowIndex based on the selected cells on a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I'm trying to get the row indices based on my selected cells on a DataGridView. How can I do that in VB.NET?

This is what I have:

```
 Dim iRowIndex As Integer
 For i = 0 To Me.grdTransaction.SelectedCells.Item(iRowIndex)
   iRowIndex = Me.grdTransaction.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex.ToString()
   Dim s As String = Me.grdTransaction.SelectedRows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6").Value
   aList.Add(s)

   MsgBox("Row index " & iRowIndex)
 Next
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @matzone I have figured it out:

```
  Dim iRowIndex As Integer

  For i As Integer = 0 To Me.grdTransaction.SelectedCells.Count - 1
    iRowIndex = Me.grdTransaction.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
    aList.Add(Me.grdTransaction.Rows(iRowIndex).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6").Value)
    MsgBox("Row index " & Format(iRowIndex))
  Next
```

Answer (score 7):

`DGV.CurrentRow.Index`

Will work even if `selectionMode = CellSelect`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I'm understanding the question.  Why does

```
iRowIndex = grdTransaction.SelectedRow.RowIndex
```

not work?

Comment: Because I'm selecting cells, not rows

Comment: Forgive me because I've never created a GridView where the user could select individual cells, but surely even if a specific cell is selected then the SelectedRow.RowIndex (or better still, the SelectedRow) property is still the index of the row the selected cell is in?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..

```
Dim iRowIndex As Integer
Dim s As String

For i as Integer = 0 To Me.grdTransaction.SelectedCells.Count -1

     iRowIndex = Me.grdTransaction.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex.ToString()
     aList.Add(Me.grdTransaction.SelectedRows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6").Value)

     MsgBox("Row index " & format(iRowIndex))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the go. I'm getting an ArgumentsOutofRange Exception